# Web app JS not running when launched from iOS 7 home screen

Tags: javascript, ios, web, mobile-safari

I have a webpage which is linked with a bunch of CSS and JS files. The page also has these tags for iOS:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

The page works just great when launched from desktop browsers as well as Mobile Safari. But, when I add it to home screen and launch from there, the JavaScript files are not executed. The CSS and images load just fine.

My page links files with relative paths like this:

```
<script src="js/parallax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you try adding the full path (so including http:// ?), what happens then?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it didn't do any good :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the CSS and JS files were being used from cache. So I added this to my PHP page, so that the files are loaded every time the page loads.

```
<script src="js/script.js?cache=<?php echo(rand(1000,9999)); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: It seems like that might go wrong occasionally because the same number comes up twice... common practice for this kind of thing is to append the current date/time, eg. using the `time()` function.